# Pass Additional header to twilio

Tags: python, twilio

When I access any api under *example.com/v3/* , I need to pass headers like ** token, clientip **, etc. and its mandatory headers.

Now when I make request to *example.com/v3/notify* , headers like token, clients are passed. This url is redirected internally to -> example.com/twilio.

I am stuck at forwarding these headers internally to the *example.com/twilio*

What shall I do to forwarded these headers as well?

Sample Code in Python which makes call to twiml_url(*example.com/twilio*):

```
client.calls.create(
            to=call_number,
            from_=TWILIO_FROM_NUMBER,
            url=twiml_url,
            method="GET",
            fallback_method="GET",
            status_callback_method="GET",
            record="false"
        )
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. What has your URL redirection got to do with Twilio making a webhook to your URL?

Comment: The header information. I need to pass the headers, so that when Twilio is making a webhook to my URL, my header validation function doesn't complains about missing headers. Those headers are compulsory, without which the web hook call will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can't get Twilio to send extra headers on your behalf. Twilio implements it's own header validation so that you can [validate requests came from Twilio itself](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/security#validating-requests).

I would recommend implementing those checks and turning off your own header validation for requests made to the URL you use for Twilio.